# How to extract Date and time from data entered as October 29, 2014 4:20PM PDT

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data that I copy and paste in this format: `October 29, 2014 4:20PM PDT`

I need a formula to extract the date in one cell and the time in another cell. I need these two values to be able to do a calculation for hour from one time to the other and use the date as a number value.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the date in cell A1 - as a string of text, e.g. prepend a single quote to it as you enter it, as in
`'october 29, 2014 4:20pm`  or alternatively as in `="october 29, 2014 4:20pm"`
Note the missing `PDT`      *(strip it off with `left(...)` or similar)*.

Then
`=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))`
will pick out the date

and
`=HOUR(A1)&":"&MINUTE(A1)`
will pick out the time.

Another approach that SHOULD work:     *LibreOffice, where I'm trying out things seems to have bug in this*
`=TIMEVALUE(A1)`
and then reformat the cell as a date or time using the dialog (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

Date/time fields are stored as an integer day number + fraction of day, ie (days_since_31Dec1899 + seconds_since_ midnight / 86400), so you don't need to split the date and time in order to perform time-shifting.

If `A1` contains a date and time, then set `B1=A1+1/24` to give one hour later. For a more general time shift, set `A2=2:15:30` and `B2=A1+A2` gives 2hr 15min 30sec later. You can of course subtract for earlier times.

You will need to format the output cells (B1/B2) as a date and time.

Answer (score 0):

As AFH described, date/time is stored as a number and then displayed according to the format you select.  The date is the integer portion and the time is the decimal fraction of a day.  AFH's answer describes how to work with the value without splitting it.  If you do need to split it, you can do it with Excel functions.  Say your date/time entry is in cell A1.

```
    =INT(A1)     gives you the date portion
    =MOD(A1,1)   gives you the time portion
```

These can each be formatted using the standard date and time formats.  Also, the date and time functions will work with each piece (as long as the function doesn't require the missing portion).  For example, WEEKDAY() will work with the date portion.